# Data encoding (PennyLane) vs feature map (Qiskit)

Tags: qiskit, pennylane, encoding

I am new to quantum machine learning and I came across data encoding (in Pennylane) and feature map (in Qiskit). What are their similarities and differences?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.